# How to install BinderHub using Helm v3

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, jupyterhub

In the zero-to-binderhub user documentation, the command to install BinderHub based on version 0.2.0-3b53fce was

`helm install jupyterhub/binderhub --version=0.2.0-3b53fce  --name=binder --namespace=binder -f secret.yaml -f config.yaml`

The above code requires helm 2 to run. **Question: How to change this installation command using helm 3?**

There is a post at https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/issues/1046 which discussed that all helm 3 compatible jupyterhub/binderhub charts have the special -n pattern preceding the digits. So run this command to get a list of helm 3 compatible charts:
`helm search repo jupyterhub/binderhub --devel -l | grep "\\-n"`
[image]

I finally installed version `0.2.0-n301.hc5e7db2` jupyterhub/binderhub chart using:

```
helm install jupyterhub jupyterhub/binderhub \
    --version=0.2.0-n301.hc5e7db2 \
    -f binderhub/secret.yaml \
    -f binderhub/config.yaml
```

Now in this deployment, the namespace is default, which is weird.

fwiw, I'm using Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) to try to deploy a BinderHub. The default helm version of my GKE is 3.2.1. Additionally, helm 2 is going to deprecate and no longer maintain very soon, that's the reason why I am seeking a way to install BinderHub using helm v3. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it need to be this specific version? I am not able to find in in repo `helm search repo -l jupyterhub/binderhub` however I am also not able to deploy other versions. Still investigating Did you try to follow [Binderhub for GKE](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/binderhub-deploy-gke)

Comment: @PjoterS Since the default helm version in GKE is 3.2.1, I'm just sticking to it. If you run helm search repo jupyterhub/binderhub --devel -l | grep "\\-n", you will see a list of jupyterhub/binderhub charts.

Comment: I mean if you need this specific binderhub version `--version=0.2.0-3b53fce`. I am asking as I couldnt find it in repo (I saw other versions). Did you try `Binderhub for GKE` from my previous comment?

Comment: I definitely do not need this binderhub version which is not helm 3 compatible. I need the version 0.2.0-n301.hc5e7db2 instead.

Comment: By the way, although I did not specify the name and namespace, I used this code ```helm install jupyterhub jupyterhub/binderhub \
    --version=0.2.0-n301.hc5e7db2 \
    -f binderhub/secret.yaml \
    -f binderhub/config.yaml
``` and worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as `Community Wiki` for better visibility as solution was mention in comments and question.

If you will deploy [Binderhub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub) on GKE using command

```
$ helm install jupyterhub/binderhub jupyterhub --version=0.2.0-3b53fce binder -f secret.yaml -f config.yaml
```

you will receive error:

`Error: failed to download "jupyterhub/binderhub" (hint: running helm repo update may help)`

Issue is related with Helm v3 standard.

> it relates to Helm3 not accepting to work with any helm chart that doesnt have a version according to the SemVer 2 standard.

**Similar issue was mention in [this github thread](https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/issues/1046).**

Also in this thread was mention that specific `jupyterhub/binderhub` charts with special `-n` pattern is compatible with Helm v3.

To list all binderhub compatible version:

```
$ helm repo add jupyterhub https://jupyterhub.github.io/helm-chart
$ helm repo update
$ helm search repo jupyterhub/binderhub --devel -l | grep "\\-n"
```

As OP stated in question, when use proper version, `secret.yaml` and `configuration.yaml` was able to deploy `jupyterhub/binderhub` chart.

```
$ helm install jupyterhub jupyterhub/binderhub \
    --version=0.2.0-n301.hc5e7db2 \
    -f binderhub/secret.yaml \
    -f binderhub/config.yaml
```

In addition, there is special `binderhub version for Google Cloud` - [BinderHub to Google Cloud](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/binderhub-deploy-gke).

Comment: Thanks for organizing the content! By the way, what is the right page in community Wiki to post this tutorial?

Comment: @son520804 In short, Community Wiki should be use to provide answer based on someone else information, or to clarify information, expand information from comments to make solution more visible for Community. Please check [Community Wiki Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) for more details. For Community Wiki you won't get reputation points but goal is to evolving source of good information.